# How to style @Html.CheckBoxFor?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsComplete , new { @class = "checkbox" })
```

Css code:

```
.сheckbox{
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: #ed495c;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: background 0.2s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And now, if you assign styles to the checkbox class, nothing changes

Update: Why this works?
`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { style="width:100px;height:25px" })`

Comment: You have deployed a css for a class called "checkbox" alongside the html?

Comment: @Ralf Added a snippet of css code